# Java HQL Query on view does not map all the returned rows

Tags: java, mysql, hql

I have a view in MySQL that joins a 1-* between Schemas and Properties.
The view works fine.  When I run a query in MySQL workbench I get the expected results.

However, when I run the same query in my Java program using HQL, the expected number of rows are being returned, but only the 1st row has data in it. That first row is correct, content-wise.

My code is fairly straightforward (I hope...). Stepping through in debug I can see that queryResult.list has the right # rows that I would expect to be returned for the input objectIdentifier(of the schema), but only the first row has on object in it.  The rest are empty. There should be one row for each joined property. As I say, the # of rows is correct.

```
    public List<SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames> getSchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNamesView(
    String schemaAndPropertiesResolvedNamesId, ServiceHeaderVO context)
    throws DALException {

List<SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames> result = new ArrayList();
try{
       Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       session.beginTransaction();
       String hql = "FROM SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames schemaandpropertiesresolvednames WHERE schemaandpropertiesresolvednames.objectIdentifier =:objectIdentifier";
       Query queryResult = session.createQuery(hql);
       queryResult.setParameter("objectIdentifier", schemaAndPropertiesResolvedNamesId);
       List<SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames> listrows = queryResult.list();
       Iterator iterator = listrows.iterator();          
       while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames obj = (SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames) iterator.next();
           result.add(obj);
       }          
       session.getTransaction().commit();
       return result;
```

It appears to be partially working to the extent that it always has the correct number of rows in the queryResult (if I try different objectIdentifiers as input).  It is just they are not populated apart from the first one.

Is the content of the view causing this?

The annoying this is I could have sworn it worked earlier.  Then I went on to make other changes elsewhere, but when I tested it again it had this problem.

Any suggestions?  This is the first time I have used HQL.

Comment: Does your `SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames.java` have a valid and unique ID / Primary Key defined?

Comment: no I don't believe so.
The property.objectIdentifier should be unique.  So I should set that as the primary key?

Does HQL need to know what the primary key is?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I've had problems with hibernate-3 entities mapped to a view when there wasn't a primary / unique key defined on the entity.  I think hibernate uses that to differentiate items in lists and cache.

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow primary keys on views (I just found out).
So my guess it is using the primary key from Schema (as the base table?) 
So I will see if I can reverse the join and have Property as the base, and see if that helps

Comment: perhaps you have to overwrite your equals method in the entities

Comment: Maybe, the problem is your HQL query. When you ommit the `SELECT` part, as you did, "strange things" can happen. So, try: `SELECT schemaandpropertiesresolvednames FROM SchemaAndPropertiesResolvedNames schemaandpropertiesresolvednames WHERE schemaandpropertiesresolvednames.objectIdentifier =:objectIdentifier`